# How to get JAVA_OPTS value in jsp

Tags: jsp, environment-variables

I am trying to get JAVA_OPTS value defined in catalina.bat in a jsp file. Can someone tell me how to do that.

For Example: My JAVA_OPTS definition in catalina.bat is like

JAVA_OPS= -DMyProjectHome=D:\Projects

I want to have the value of MyProjectHome at run time in jsp file so I am trying to do is ${MyProjectHome} but it is doing nothing.

Or is there a way I can define JAVA_OPTS value in

Please help me out achieving my functionality.

thanks.

Comment: Try System.getenv("MyProjectHome")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you pass to a JVM with `-Dfoo=bar` is called a system property. You can get their value using [`System.getProperty()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperty%28java.lang.String%29). There is no standard tag or JSP EL syntax to get them, though, so you'll have to use scriptlet or implement a custom tag.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in a class which extends a `Map`.

```
public class SystemProperties extends HashMap<String, String> {

    @Override
    public String get(Object name) {
        return System.getProperty(name != null ? name.toString() : null);
    }

}
```

Declare it as follows in JSP.

```
<jsp:useBean id="systemProperties" class="com.example.SystemProperties" scope="application" />
```

Then you can just treat it as `Map` in EL.

```
${systemProperties['MyProjectHome']}
```

or

```
${systemProperties.MyProjectHome}
```

Comment: It might be better to extend AbstractMap, rather than HashMap.  Or even just implement Map.  If you extend HashMap, you get all the memory footprint of HashMap's members (like it's table array) which you will never need to use.  You will have to implement a few extra methods, though (but can safely just throw UnsupportedOperations in them).

Answer (score 1):

Those are Java system properties.  You can access it via the Java function

```
System.getProperty("MyProjectHome");
```

There might be a better way to do it in JSP but that will work.