# Get java enviorment parameters from JSP file

Tags: java, jsp, jvm-arguments

I am new to JSP and I am wondering if it is possible to get java runtime parameters from whithin a JSP file (display it on the web page). The thing I am looking for is the `javaagent` option, I want to show all the java agents that the enviorment is using.

On my linux machine I can write

`ps -ax | grep java`

and all the parameters are shown, and the java agent will be visible: `-javaagent:/Path/Agent.jar`

Is there any way to see the agent of the server?

Explanation: I am running my application on a web server, and I have a JSP page which runs on it, and I want to get the above parameters.

Edit2 : This is not a duplicate of the enviorment variable question since the javaagent doesnt appear in the enviorment variables, one way to add a java agent is via the JAVA_OPTS variable but its not the case here.

Comment: `the distant server` --- huh? What? Why would you even want to retrieve such weird information? What has this to do with JSP?

Comment: @specializt hi, I edited the question with more information.

Comment: @Smutje please read edit2 in the question, the javaagent doesnt appear in the enviorment variables

Comment: yet again : **what has this to do with a `distant server`??**

Comment: @specializt I have changed it to server, it really doesnt matter if its local or not

Comment: that is a **big** difference, one is about retrieving JVM-parameters and the other is about transmitting them over the internet - its like comparing apples to space shuttles and claiming theres "no difference"

Comment: try checking this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234620/how-to-get-java-opts-value-in-jsp

Comment: I don't know if this works from within a jsp, but it's worth a try: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13958318/is-it-possible-to-get-the-command-used-to-launch-the-jvm-in-java

Comment: @specializt I want to print the variable to the web page and show it as a web page content, I really dont see how this matters if I print it on my local server and if I print it on the distant server

Comment: i think you need to do some research about IT basics first ... especially the topic "client & server".  Values on distant servers are different from the ones on your local instance.